# How does Find() Linq Work? how does base the find(id)?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Basically I know that find() works when it checks the entity by the stated primary id. My question is I have a Model and one of its property have [Key] data annotation but this column is not the actual primary key in the database. 
Something like this

```
public class ModelMetadata (I'm using a metadata)
{
     public int ID{get;set;} <<--actual rownum or db id   
     [Key]
     public guid ItemId{get;set;} <<-- my desired id for find() 
     public string prop1{get;set;}   
}
```

now if I use dbcontext.Model.Find(id) will it return the result based on the 'ItemId'? or the actual assign Primary key 'ID'?

Thank you.

Comment: It will use whatever you've told it through your model conventions/data annotations/fluent configuration. In youa case, you are telling EF that `ItemId` is the PK, so it will use that field (and the corresponding db table column).

Comment: Does this actually have anything to do with C?  Certainly the code presented is not valid C.

Comment: It is a metadata class for the model, so it is a valid c# code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a where conditional single or default like

```
User myUser = myDBContext.Users.SingleOrDefault(user => user.Username == username);
```

Comment: `SingleOrDefault` has to examine the entire table to ensure there's only one result, rather than returning as soon as it finds it. `FirstOrDefault` is preferable.

Comment: it's a guid, i'll be passing that as a key or the real Id.

Answer (score 0):

From [Programming Entity Framework: DbContext](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920022237.do):

> One of the great things about Find is that it doesn't unnecessarily
>   query the database. It's also capable of finding newly added objects
>   that haven't yet been saved to the database. Find uses a simple set of
>   rules to locate the object (in order of precedence):
>
> 1. Look in memory for an existing entity that has been loaded from the database or attached to the context.
> 2. Look at added objects that have not yet been saved to the database.
> 3. Look in the database for entities that have not yet been loaded into memory.